# Dask task stream finishing much faster than actual computation

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, bag

I am attempting to run a process in parallel using dask.bag, but the process is taking longer than the task stream seems to suggest.

- I am on dask version 2023.9.3
- I am on a single machine

```
        start = time.time()
        def combine_shader_polygons(i):
            shader_polygon = None
            shader_indices = np.flatnonzero(shading_candidates_np[i])
            if len(shader_indices) == 0:
                pass
            elif len(shader_indices) == 1:
                shader_polygon = reference_gdf.loc[shader_indices].iloc[0]
            else:
                polygons = reference_gdf.loc[shader_indices]
                shader_polygon = polygons.unary_union
            return shader_polygon

        shader_polygons = bag.map(combine_shader_polygons).compute(scheduler='processes')
        timer = round(time.time() - start, 2)
        print(f'Checkpoint 1: {timer}s')
```

As you can see in the task stream image below, the process from start to finish takes around 350ms.  But the print statement returns 5.3s.  Is there a way to see what is taking up the rest of the time?

[image: Dask Task Stream]

Comment: Starting processes, building the graph, giving tasks to workers, all that takes time. 5s is really a small amount of time, using distributed processing always come with some overhead. You won't be able to see it yet, but when performing computations for at least several minutes, with tasks during more than one seconds, it will become negligible.